# Generating a TreeView component with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to build a TreeView component in React and doing the following.

```
import React from 'react';

/* components */
import {TreeNode} from './TreeNodeComponent';

export const TreeView = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      parent: [
        {
          text: "Parent",
          children:[
            {
              text: 'Child',
              children: [
                {
                  text: 'Grandchild',
                  children: [
                    { text: Date() },
                    { text: Date() },
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  render(){
    let parents = this.state.parent;
    let nodes = advertisers.map( (n, i)=>{
        return <TreeNode key={i} node={n} children={n.children} />
    });

    return(
      <ul>
        {nodes}
      </ul>
    )
  }
})
```

Then the TreeNode component is like the following

```
import React from 'react';

export const TreeNode = React.createClass ({

  render(){

    let nodes = this.props.children.map( (n, i)=>{
      let element = n.children ? <TreeNode key={i} node={n} children={n.children} /> : <TreeNode key={i} node={n} children={[]} />
        return element
    });

    return(
      <span>
        <li>{this.props.node.text}</li>
        <ul>{nodes}</ul>
      </span>
    )
  }
})
```

Here I am passing an empty array to the children prop if the next one doesn't have any children. But this generates an empty UL (as it should) - Is there a better way to do this? Should I do the check before maping over the children props?

Comment: I might do as you say and not even bother rendering the child component if no children (put the check outside of it), but otherwise your logic is good. I personally might break up the ternary out to something a little more functional so it's more clear, but that's just personal preference :).